# How do DataContracts work? - Deserialize Json

Tags: asp.net, json, deserialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I grabbed an example off of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115037/problem-with-deserializing-json-on-datamember-type/4119681#4119681), and built my own custom Google Maps object used for deserializing the json object.

Now the code works like a champ, but I just need an explanation on why/how it works.  Does the serializer "try" to match up names, or is something else going on.

**What exactly is this doing?**

Here's the **working** code.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Namespace Utilities.Apis
    Public NotInheritable Class GoogleGeolocate


        Private Const googleUrl As String = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&sensor=false"
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Shared Function GetLatLon(ByVal address As String) As String
            ''# This is just here to prevent "placeholder" data from being submitted.
            If address = "6789 university drive" Then
                Return Nothing
            End If

            address = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address)

            Dim url = String.Format(googleUrl, address)

            Dim request = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate")
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            Dim serializer As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(GoogleResponse))
            Dim res = DirectCast(serializer.ReadObject(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()), GoogleResponse)

            Dim resources As GoogleResponse.Result = res.results(0)
            Dim point = resources.geometry.location.lat
            Dim latlon As New GeolocationLatLon
            With latlon
                .latitude = resources.geometry.location.lat
                .longitude = resources.geometry.location.lng
            End With

            Dim jsonSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer

            Return jsonSerializer.Serialize(latlon)
        End Function
    End Class

    <DataContract()>
    Public Class GoogleResponse
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property results() As Result()
        <DataContract()>
        Public Class Result
            <DataMember()>
            Public Property geometry As m_Geometry
            <DataContract()>
            Public Class m_Geometry
                <DataMember()>
                Public Property location As m_location
                <DataContract()>
                Public Class m_location
                    <DataMember()>
                    Public Property lat As String
                    <DataMember()>
                    Public Property lng As String
                End Class
            End Class
        End Class

    End Class
End Namespace
```

And here's the GeolocationLatLon Poco

```
Public Class GeolocationLatLon
    Public latitude As String
    Public longitude As String
End Class
```

When I call the code, it's really quite simple.
*note, this is an MVC controller, that has nothing to do "really" with the question other than to show what I'm doing*

```
    Function GeoLocation(ByVal address As String) As ContentResult
        Return New ContentResult With {.Content = GoogleGeolocate.GetLatLon(address),
                                       .ContentType = "application/json"}
    End Function
```

And the final result is

> {"latitude":"50.124300","longitude":"-114.4979990"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, DataContractJsonSerializer maps JSON name/value pairs to an XML infoset. In fact, DataContractJsonSerializer is built on top of the XML-based DataContractSerializer and processes every JSON input and JSON output as if it were dealing with XML. There is a higher-level abstraction layer (a JSON writer and a JSON reader, as exposed via JsonReaderWriterFactory) that actually translates this XML to JSON and JSON back to internal XML.

See this [excellent overview (Mapping Between JSON and XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924435.aspx) to see what happens to DataContractJsonSerializer internally and how it pulls all this off.