# Deserializing JSON as a Generic List

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a filter string as shown in the below format:

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"FName","op":"bw","data":"te"}]}
```

I need to deserialize this as a Generic list of items.

Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Comment: [DataContracts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289073/how-do-datacontracts-work-deserialize-json)

Comment: yes, i have created a class and tried to deseridlized by using the below code.IList<FilterClass> filterData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<FilterClass>>(filter);

Comment: Have you written a DataContract in order to store the Deserialized data?

Comment: public class FilterClass
    {
        public string groupOp
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string field
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string op
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string data
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class like so:

**Deserialization code**

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

...

string json = "{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"FName\",\"op\":\"bw\",\"data\":\"te\"}]}";
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Filter filter = (Filter)serializer.Deserialize<Filter>(json);
```

**Classes**

```
public class Filter
{
    public string GroupOp { get; set; }
    public List<Rule> Rules { get; set; }

    public Filter()
    {
        Rules = new List<Rule>();
    }
}

public class Rule
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Op { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a "generic" list. Here you had to define the classes, so if the JSON were to change format, somebody would have to make updates to the class.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/).  It allows you to do things like:

```
JObject o = new JObject(
  new JProperty("Name", "John Smith"),
  new JProperty("BirthDate", new DateTime(1983, 3, 20))
  );

JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
Person p = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(new JTokenReader(o), typeof(Person));

Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
// John Smith
```

Source: [the documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ReadingWritingJSON.html).