# .NET DataContractJsonSerializer, Nested collections throwing me for a loop

Tags: asp.net, json, datacontract, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm working on a class to get the Latitude and Longitude of an address by 3  different providers (just for comparison sake).

*Note, this might look like a lot to look at, but some info is just there for reference if you want. Data below the `<hr>` is not necessary to look at.*

My Google Maps DataContract works like a champ. But my Bing and MapQuest DataContracts aren't playing so nice. I think the issue has to deal with the *Nested collections* of the JSON for Bing and MapQuest, and I just don't know how to deal with them.

Here is the Function that processes the Data.

```
        ''# Because the JSON Response from Google, MapQuest, and Bing are drastically
        ''# different, we need to consume the response a little differently
        ''# for each API. 


        ''# ##################################
        ''# BING IS BROKEN
        ''# ##################################
        ''# Here we're handling the Bing Provider
        If Provider = apiProvider.Bing Then
            Dim res = DirectCast(serializer.ReadObject(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()), BingResponse)
            Dim resources As BingResponse.ResourceSet.Resource = res.resourceSets(0).resources(0)
            Dim point = resources.point
            With coordinates
                .latitude = point.coordinates(0)
                .longitude = point.coordinates(1)
            End With



        ''# ##################################
        ''# GOOGLE WORKS LIKE A CHAMP
        ''# ##################################
            ''# Here we're handling the Google Provider
        ElseIf Provider = apiProvider.Google Then
            Dim res = DirectCast(serializer.ReadObject(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()), GoogleResponse)
            Dim resources As GoogleResponse.Result = res.results(0)
            Dim point = resources.geometry.location
            With coordinates
                .latitude = point.lat
                .longitude = point.lng
            End With



        ''# ##################################
        ''# MAPQUEST IS BROKEN
        ''# ##################################
            ''# Here we're handling the MapQuest Provider
        ElseIf Provider = apiProvider.MapQuest Then
            Dim res = DirectCast(serializer.ReadObject(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()), MapQuestResponse)
            Dim resources As MapQuestResponse.Result = res.results(0)
            Dim point = resources.locations.latLng
            With coordinates
                .latitude = point.lat
                .longitude = point.lng
            End With
        End If
```

And here are the three DataContracts

```
''# A comment to fix SO Code Coloring
<DataContract()>
Public Class BingResponse
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property resourceSets() As ResourceSet()
    <DataContract()>
    Public Class ResourceSet
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property resources() As Resource()
        <DataContract([Namespace]:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1", name:="Location")>
        Public Class Resource
            <DataMember()>
            Public Property point() As m_Point
            <DataContract()>
            Public Class m_Point
                <DataMember()>
                Public Property coordinates() As String()
            End Class
        End Class
    End Class
End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class GoogleResponse
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property results() As Result()
    <DataContract()>
    Public Class Result
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property geometry As m_Geometry
        <DataContract()>
        Public Class m_Geometry
            <DataMember()>
            Public Property location As m_location
            <DataContract()>
            Public Class m_location
                <DataMember()>
                Public Property lat As String
                <DataMember()>
                Public Property lng As String
            End Class
        End Class
    End Class
End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class MapQuestResponse
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property results() As Result()
    <DataContract()>
    Public Class Result
        <DataMember()>
        Public Property locations As m_Locations
        <DataContract()>
        Public Class m_Locations
            <DataMember()>
            Public Property latLng As m_latLng
            <DataContract()>
            Public Class m_latLng
                <DataMember()>
                Public Property lat As String
                <DataMember()>
                Public Property lng As String
            End Class
        End Class
    End Class
End Class
```

When testing **MapQuest** I get this error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   on line

```
.latitude = point.lat
```

When testing **Bing** I get this error

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   on line

```
Dim resources As BingResponse.ResourceSet.Resource = res.resourceSets(0).resources(0)
```

---

FYI, I'll also post what the JSON Response for each looks like.

### Google Maps

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": [ "bus_station", "transit_station" ],
    "formatted_address": "Microsoft Way & Microsoft ACS, Redmond, WA 98052, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "Microsoft Way & Microsoft ACS",
      "short_name": "Microsoft Way & Microsoft ACS",
      "types": [ "bus_station", "transit_station" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Redmond",
      "short_name": "Redmond",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "East Seattle",
      "short_name": "East Seattle",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "King",
      "short_name": "King",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Washington",
      "short_name": "WA",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "98052",
      "short_name": "98052",
      "types": [ "postal_code" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 47.6397018,
        "lng": -122.1305080
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 47.6365542,
          "lng": -122.1336556
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 47.6428494,
          "lng": -122.1273604
        }
      }
    },
    "partial_match": true
  }, {
    "types": [ "bus_station", "transit_station" ],
    "formatted_address": "Microsoft Way & NE 36th St, Redmond, WA 98052, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "Microsoft Way & NE 36th St",
      "short_name": "Microsoft Way & NE 36th St",
      "types": [ "bus_station", "transit_station" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Redmond",
      "short_name": "Redmond",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "East Seattle",
      "short_name": "East Seattle",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "King",
      "short_name": "King",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Washington",
      "short_name": "WA",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "98052",
      "short_name": "98052",
      "types": [ "postal_code" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 47.6420593,
        "lng": -122.1306990
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 47.6389117,
          "lng": -122.1338466
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 47.6452069,
          "lng": -122.1275514
        }
      }
    },
    "partial_match": true
  }, {
    "types": [ "bus_station", "transit_station" ],
    "formatted_address": "Microsoft Way & NE 31ST St, Redmond, WA 98052, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "Microsoft Way & NE 31ST St",
      "short_name": "Microsoft Way & NE 31ST St",
      "types": [ "bus_station", "transit_station" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Redmond",
      "short_name": "Redmond",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "East Seattle",
      "short_name": "East Seattle",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "King",
      "short_name": "King",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Washington",
      "short_name": "WA",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "98052",
      "short_name": "98052",
      "types": [ "postal_code" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 47.6380959,
        "lng": -122.1318050
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 47.6349483,
          "lng": -122.1349526
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 47.6412435,
          "lng": -122.1286574
        }
      }
    },
    "partial_match": true
  }, {
    "types": [ "route" ],
    "formatted_address": "Microsoft w Campus Acrd, Redmond, WA, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "Microsoft w Campus Acrd",
      "short_name": "Microsoft w Campus Acrd",
      "types": [ "route" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Redmond",
      "short_name": "Redmond",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "East Seattle",
      "short_name": "East Seattle",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "King",
      "short_name": "King",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Washington",
      "short_name": "WA",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 47.6582970,
        "lng": -122.1414390
      },
      "location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 47.6559394,
          "lng": -122.1435435
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 47.6622346,
          "lng": -122.1372482
        }
      },
      "bounds": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 47.6577719,
          "lng": -122.1433446
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 47.6604021,
          "lng": -122.1374471
        }
      }
    },
    "partial_match": true
  } ]
}
```

### Bing Maps

```
{ "authenticationResultCode" : "ValidCredentials",
  "brandLogoUri" : "http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png",
  "copyright" : "Copyright © 2011 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
  "resourceSets" : [ { "estimatedTotal" : 1,
        "resources" : [ { "__type" : "Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
              "address" : { "addressLine" : "1 Microsoft Way",
                  "adminDistrict" : "WA",
                  "countryRegion" : "United States",
                  "formattedAddress" : "1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052",
                  "locality" : "Redmond",
                  "postalCode" : "98052"
                },
              "bbox" : [ 47.636682837606166,
                  -122.13698544771381,
                  47.644408272747519,
                  -122.12169881991093
                ],
              "confidence" : "High",
              "entityType" : "Address",
              "name" : "1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052",
              "point" : { "coordinates" : [ 47.640545555176843,
                      -122.12934213381237
                    ],
                  "type" : "Point"
                }
            } ]
      } ],
  "statusCode" : 200,
  "statusDescription" : "OK",
  "traceId" : "3d0dd6c4ea1f4c4ba6f9c7211a5abf75|BAYM001222|02.00.82.2800|BY2MSNVM001058"
}
```

### MapQuest

```
{ "info" : { "copyright" : { "imageAltText" : "© 2011 MapQuest, Inc.",
          "imageUrl" : "http://tile21.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
          "text" : "© 2011 MapQuest, Inc."
        },
      "messages" : [  ],
      "statuscode" : 0
    },
  "options" : { "ignoreLatLngInput" : false,
      "maxResults" : -1,
      "thumbMaps" : true
    },
  "results" : [ { "locations" : [ { "adminArea1" : "US",
              "adminArea1Type" : "Country",
              "adminArea3" : "WA",
              "adminArea3Type" : "State",
              "adminArea4" : "King County",
              "adminArea4Type" : "County",
              "adminArea5" : "Redmond",
              "adminArea5Type" : "City",
              "displayLatLng" : { "lat" : 47.674197999999997,
                  "lng" : -122.1203
                },
              "dragPoint" : false,
              "geocodeQuality" : "CITY",
              "geocodeQualityCode" : "A5XCX",
              "latLng" : { "lat" : 47.674197999999997,
                  "lng" : -122.1203
                },
              "linkId" : 0,
              "mapUrl" : "http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v3/getmap?type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,47.674198,-122.1203,0,0|&center=47.674198,-122.1203&zoom=9&key=Fmjtd|luu22q01ng,2n=o5-h6rnq&rand=-47567557",
              "postalCode" : "",
              "sideOfStreet" : "N",
              "street" : "",
              "type" : "s"
            } ],
        "providedLocation" : { "location" : "1 Microsoft Way, Redmon WA" }
      } ]
}
```

### Addition

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nevermind, didn't see the scroll bars.

Comment: I edited it down to focus on the relevant data.

Comment: Could the lat/lng returning as number for mapquest need to be a decimal in your data contract?  Edit:  No, google maps is the same.  I'll watch to see the answer, I'm intrested.

Comment: I added a screenshot showing that `latLng` is coming up null

Comment: Shouldn't Public Property locations As m_Locations be Public Property locations() As m_Locations()?  I assume this is array notation in VB.  It would seem you're taking the latLng from the Array object and not the instance of the location in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For map quest:

Shouldn't `Public Property locations As m_Locations` be `Public Property locations() As m_Locations()`?  I assume this is array notation in VB.  It would seem you're taking the latLng from the Array object and not the instance of the location in the array.

Found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115037/problem-with-deserializing-json-on-datamember-type) with a data contract (accepted answer) for the same response.  Looking for differences but not spotting them yet...

Comment: Haha, yeah. That was exactly the problem for MapQuest.

Comment: And it turns out the problem I was having with BING was that I was sending the city and province, that it didn't like

Comment: Glad I could help, it always takes that second set of eyes.

Comment: You bet. Funny how to little brackets can make one want to gouge their eyes out. Thanks again!