# XML deserialization error in Xamarin Android on List<int> marked with [XmlAttribute]

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xmlserializer

I have a problem deserializing an object that is used in a multi-platform project on both Windows and Xamarin Android.

The `ConfigProperty` class is created, used and filled by the program and then serialized to XML for storage. Upon reading and deserializing the class in Android, I get a `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: elementType`. Deserializing in Windows works flawlessly.

I narrowed the problem down to the `DeviceIdentifierIndices` property, a list of integers. When the attribute is not present, i.e. the list was empty on serialization, deserialization also works. What is really strange is that it also works on both platforms when the list is serialized as a usual XML element and not as an XML attribute.

Right now I am in a phase where I could change from attribute to element, but I'd prefer to keep it as an attribute.

The class in question looks like this, but the problem exists on other classes as well:

```
public class ConfigProperty
{
    public ushort E2Address { get; set; }
    public string NameKey { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionKey { get; set; }
    public Visibility Visibility { get; set; }                // 0: Invisible 1: R 2: RW 3: W
    [XmlAttribute]
    public List<int> DeviceIdentifierIndices { get; private set; }
    ...

    public ConfigProperty() 
    {
        NameKey = string.Empty;
        DescriptionKey = string.Empty;
        Visibility = Visibility.ReadWrite;
        DeviceIdentifierIndices = new List<int>();
        ...
    }
}
```

The generated XML looks like this:

```xml
<ConfigProperty DeviceIdentifierIndices="18 22">
    <E2Address>327</E2Address>
    <NameKey>lightningInterval</NameKey>
    <DescriptionKey>lightningIntervalDescription</DescriptionKey>
    <Visibility>2</Visibility>
    ...
</ConfigProperty>
```

XML de-/serialization is done with ordinary `XmlSerializers`:

```
public static void Serialize<T>(T data, Stream stream)
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        CloseOutput = false,
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        Indent = true
    };

    using(XmlWriter tw = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        xs.Serialize(tw, data);
    }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream stream)
{
    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)xs.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}

...

ConfigProperty config = Export.XmlExport.Deserialize<ConfigProperty>(inputStream);
```

Here is the stack trace of the failed deserialization attempt:

```
{System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: elementType
  at System.Array.CreateInstance (System.Type elementType, System.Int32[] lengths) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System/Array.cs:471 
  at System.Array.CreateInstance (System.Type elementType, System.Int32 length) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System/Array.cs:451 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadListString (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.String values) [0x00044] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:725 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.GetValueFromXmlString (System.String value, System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:658 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadAttributeMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, System.Boolean isValueList) [0x00030] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:255 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, System.Boolean isValueList, System.Boolean readBySoapOrder) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:295 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstanceMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:240 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstance (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Boolean isNullable, System.Boolean checkType) [0x000c4] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:230 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObject (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Boolean isNullable, System.Boolean checkType) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:193 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObjectElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapElementInfo elem) [0x00059] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:632 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadListElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Boolean isNullable, System.Object list, System.Boolean canCreateInstance) [0x000d7] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:696 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, System.Boolean isValueList, System.Boolean readBySoapOrder) [0x00490] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:423 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstanceMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:240 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstance (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Boolean isNullable, System.Boolean checkType) [0x000c4] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:230 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObject (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Boolean isNullable, System.Boolean checkType) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:193 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObjectElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapElementInfo elem) [0x00059] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:632 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadListElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Boolean isNullable, System.Object list, System.Boolean canCreateInstance) [0x000d7] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:696 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, System.Boolean isValueList, System.Boolean readBySoapOrder) [0x00549] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:435 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstanceMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:240 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstance (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Boolean isNullable, System.Boolean checkType) [0x000c4] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:230 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObject (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Boolean isNullable, System.Boolean checkType) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:193 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping rootMap) [0x00056] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:184 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot () [0x00022] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:87 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader reader) [0x0005e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs:381 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader) [0x00026] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs:358 
  at Export.XmlExport.Deserialize[T] (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x0002d] in C:\Projekte\xxx\Code\Export\XmlExport.cs:91 
  at Config.DeviceConfigInfo.FromStream (System.IO.Stream inputStream, Config.DeviceConfigInfoType type) [0x00118] in C:\Projekte\xxx\Code\Config\DeviceConfig.cs:872 
  at Config.DeviceConfigInfo.FromUri (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri, System.Boolean decrypt) [0x0001d] in C:\Projekte\xxx\Code\Config\DeviceConfig.cs:816 
  at xxx.Activities.WorkspaceActivity.OnActivityResult (System.Int32 requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data) [0x00085] in C:\Projekte\xxx\Activities\WorkspaceActivity.cs:249 }
```

Comment: The 18 22 is not a ushort.  Either make it a string or you need int the get/set a method to parse to a ushort.

Comment: Does it work if you change the type to `string`? It probably does, I would assume that the XmlSerializer doesn't understand how to create an int array of "18 22". I think by default attirbutes, only support primitives. To customize this behavior, you would probably have to implement `IXmlSerializable` and do your own parsing of that attribute.

Comment: The XML has been created by the ```XmlSerializer``` and not by myself. It is working on Windows, but not on Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987414/deserialization-error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-type

Comment: @Bruno: The linked problem is similar, but not the same. It seems the solution to this (JSON-related) problem was to deserialize the object using a dedicated type. However, in my case this has always been done, see edited posting above. Also, an XML serialized on Android is the same as one serialized on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing class is taking advantage of the following obscurely documented functionality of `XmlSerializer`, namely that [`[XmlAttribute]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) can be applied to a collection of primitives, and the collection will be serialized as an XML attribute whose value is a space-separated sequence of primitive values.

Specifically, the [Remarks for `XmlAttributeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) state:

> You can assign the XmlAttributeAttribute only to public fields or public properties that return a value **(or array of values)** that can be mapped to one of the XML Schema definition language (XSD) simple types (including all built-in datatypes derived from the XSD anySimpleType type). The possible types include any that can be mapped to the XSD simple types, including Guid, Char, and enumerations.

But how exactly is an "array of values" serialized as a string?  If I simplify your model as follows:

```
public class ConfigProperty
{
    public string NameKey { get; set; }
    // Remainder of properties omitted for brevity
    [XmlAttribute]
    public List<int> DeviceIdentifierIndices { get; private set; }

    public ConfigProperty()
    {
        NameKey = string.Empty;
        DeviceIdentifierIndices = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

And generate an XSD for it using `xsd.exe`, I get:

```xml
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ConfigProperty" nillable="true" type="ConfigProperty" />
  <xs:complexType name="ConfigProperty">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NameKey" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="DeviceIdentifierIndices" use="required">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:list itemType="xs:int" />
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Where `<xs:list>` is [documented by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms256162(v=vs.85)) to *Define a collection of a single **simpleType** definition* and [W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1 Part 2: Datatypes 2.4.1.2 List Datatypes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#list-datatypes) states

> The ·lexical space· of a ·list· datatype is a set of ·literals· each of which is a space-separated sequence of ·literals· of the ·item type·.

And that is why `DeviceIdentifierIndices` serializes successfully as `"18 22"` on .Net.

All that being said, this is very obscure functionality.  It's quite possible that the Mono team never implemented or tested this functionality properly.  (This [similar-sounding Unity forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unidentifiable-problem-in-list-serialization-deserialization.540244/) suggests others are seeing the same problem.)  Thus you may need to modify your class to work around the limitation.

I don't have Xamarin Android available for testing, but it's possible that replacing the list with an array would cure the problem:

```
public class ConfigProperty
{
    public string NameKey { get; set; }
    // Remainder of properties omitted for brevity

    [XmlAttribute("DeviceIdentifierIndices")]
    public int[] DeviceIdentifierIndicesArray
    {
        get { return DeviceIdentifierIndices.ToArray(); }
        set
        {
            DeviceIdentifierIndices.Clear();
            if (value != null)
                DeviceIdentifierIndices.AddRange(value);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<int> DeviceIdentifierIndices { get; private set; }

    public ConfigProperty()
    {
        NameKey = string.Empty;
        DeviceIdentifierIndices = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

And in fact, the Mono source for [`XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadListString()`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/2058deb70f3af29e569a29baf2a657add58e88eb/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs#L713) seems to assume that `listType` is an **array type** (rather than a generic type like `List<int>`) so this might well work for you.  (**Update**: OP writes [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873128/xml-deserialization-error-in-xamarin-android-on-listint-marked-with-xmlattrib/62971547?noredirect=1#comment111428814_62971547): *I have successfully tried your first solution as this seems the cleanest to me* so this is the recommended solution.)

If not, creating a surrogate string property and doing the parsing manually should work:

```
public class ConfigProperty
{
    public string NameKey { get; set; }
    // Remainder of properties omitted for brevity

    [XmlAttribute("DeviceIdentifierIndices")]
    public string XmlDeviceIdentifierIndices
    {
        get { return String.Join(" ", DeviceIdentifierIndices.Select(i => XmlConvert.ToString(i))); }
        set
        {
            var newList = (value ?? "").Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => XmlConvert.ToInt32(s)).ToList();
            DeviceIdentifierIndices.Clear();
            DeviceIdentifierIndices.AddRange(newList);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<int> DeviceIdentifierIndices { get; private set; }

    public ConfigProperty()
    {
        NameKey = string.Empty;
        DeviceIdentifierIndices = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Note however that the XSD generated for the second workaround class will not be identical to the XSD from the original class.

Serializing `DeviceIdentifierIndices` as an element rather than an attribute will also work because collections of simple types are not serialized as list datatypes when serialized as an element, instead they are serialized as sequences of elements, possibly with a container element, which uses a completely different code path.

Demo fiddle exchanging XML between the three classes here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3PmZHv

Comment: Thank you @dbc for this very detailed answer! It seems possible that this feature was never really tested in Mono.
I have successfully tried your first solution as this seems the cleanest to me.