# How to cast an object to a not known generic type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I want to build a generic method to call many Web API like Bing Maps. For this question, I use the class from : [Problem with deserializing JSON on datamember "__type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115037/problem-with-deserializing-json-on-datamember-type) which work well.

I don't exactly know how to cast **ser.ReadObject(a.Result)** to the type I give as generic parameter, in this case *LocationQueryResponse*.

```
public static void GetResponse<TDataContract>(Uri uri, Action<TDataContract> callback)
            where TDataContract : IDataContract, new()
        {
            var contract = new TDataContract();
            var contractType = contract.GetType();

            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.OpenReadCompleted += (o, a) =>
            {
                if (callback != null)
                {
                    var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TDataContract));
                    callback(Convert.ChangeType(ser.ReadObject(a.Result), contractType));
                }
            };

            wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);
        }
```

For now I get this error: 
The type parameter 'TDataContract' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint  Infrastructure

Every class that communicate with a Web API inherit of IDataContract interface.
Anyone can help?

Thank you,

David

Comment: Have you tried where TDataContract: IDataContract, new(), class?  Though I think you might be able to do this in a easier way...

Comment: What could be the easier way?

Comment: What about using a JSON serializer that works with generics.  Possibly this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Good Idea, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do an actual cast of the type when making your callback, no need to convert the type as you have read the object with the serialiser:

```
public static void GetResponse<TDataContract>(Uri uri, Action<TDataContract> callback)
            where TDataContract : IDataContract, class, new()
{
    var contract = new TDataContract();
    var contractType = contract.GetType();

    var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    wc.OpenReadCompleted += (o, a) =>
    {
        if (callback != null)
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TDataContract));
            var obj = ser.ReadObject(a.Result);
            callback((TDataContract)obj);
        }
    };

    wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `class` to your `where` directive:

```
where TDataContract : IDataContract, class, new()
```

Comment: It didn't work. I have this error: cannot convert from 'object' to 'TDataContract' + the same error I wrote in my question =(